# Asymptotic Upper Bound

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity, upperbound

Hi I solved a question with recursion tree method. Then I reached the below equatition. 
 `n
 ∑ 3^(i-1)(n - (i - 1))
i=1`

I need to find asymptotic upper bound for that equation. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha is a great tool for this: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(3%5E(i-1)(n+-+i+%2B+1)+for+i+%3D+1..n)

That tool simplifies the sum to: `(-2n + 3^(n+1) - 3)/4`.

In terms of big-O, that's O(3^n).

Comment: Paul Hankin: Do you think this O(3^n) is correct. I could not verify it with substitution method.

Comment: If so what is the lower order term for 3^n ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're asking. I don't know what the substitution method is, nor what you mean by the lower order term.

Comment: (3^(n+1)-3-2n)/4 is certainly O(3^n), since it's immediate that it's less than 3/4 * 3^n, just by discarding the negative terms.

Answer (score 0):

Let u(n) = 3^(n-1) + 2*3^(n-2) + ... + n, then
u(n+1) = (3^n + 3^(n-1) + ... + 1) + 3^(n-1) + 2*3^(n-2) + ... + n = (3^(n+1)-1)/2 + u(n) = 3*u(n) + n + 1 
u(n) = (3^(n+1) - 2n - 3) / 4.